# python : searching through nested list by key and storing it into nested list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a nested list like:

```
list1 = [(A,0.75),(D,0.49),(Y,0.36)]
```

I have a reference nested list like:

```
mainlist = [(A,10),(B,20),(C,30),(D,40),(E,50).........,(Y,250),(Z,260)]
```

1. I want to search for key element A in mainlist.
2. Once A is found in mainlist, store corresponding key,value pair in a new nested list.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 for D and Y.(all elements in list1)

I want output as:

```
newlist = [(A,1),(D,4),(Y,250)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
list1 = [('A',0.75),('D',0.49),('Y',0.36)]
mainlist = [('A',10),('B',20),('C',30),('D',40),('E',50),('Y',250),('Z',260)]

keys = {k[0] for k in list1} # create a set with keys from list1
newlist = [k for k in mainlist if k[0] in keys] # get items from mainlist with good keys 
print(newlist)
```

### Output:

```
[('A', 10), ('D', 40), ('Y', 250)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that the `set` @Sait used in his (quite beautiful) solution is an unordered data structure of unique items:

- **unordered**: meaning you can not safely assume that the order of the keys will still be `'A', 'D', 'Y'` in the set.
- **unique**: meaning that if you have repeated keys, like `'A', 'D', 'Y', 'A'`, only `'A', 'D', 'Y'` would show up in your output, as each item can only appear once in a set.

That said, you could save yourself some trouble by using a dictionary for your lookups instead of a list of tuples.

```
>>> list1 = [('A',0.75),('D',0.49),('Y',0.36),('D',0.49)]
>>> maindict = dict({'A':10, 'B':20, 'C':30, 'D':40, 'E':50, 'Y':250, 'Z':260})

>>> keys, values = zip(*list1) # unzip the tuples in list one into two separate lists
>>> newlist = [(key, maindict[key]) for key in keys]
>>> print(newlist)
[('A', 10), ('D', 40), ('Y', 250), ('D', 40)]
```

This solution is guaranteed to preserve the order of your input and can handle repeated keys as well. By using a dictionary do not need to iterate over the whole `mainlist` to find your keys. You can iterate over your keys and get their values by a single lookup of the dictionary (which is quite fast) per key.